# 表を辞書型に直す再帰関数について

Tags: python, アルゴリズム

画像のような表があり、それを下記のようなjson型に変形したいと考えています。
（途中にリストはないものとしました。）
再帰関数を使って組もうとしているのですが、途中のキーが飛んでしまったりとうまく組めずにいます。
アルゴリズムに強い方、お力添えいただけないでしょうか？

使用モジュール
openpyxl

試した実装
キーで同じレベルのものをリスト化（①）し、下位のレベルのものも同様にリスト化（②）。
forで①のリストを回わし、対応する②のリストに含まれる数が2以上の場合、再帰させ、数が1の場合returnする

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
[{
    "k1": {
        "k2": {
            "k3": "v3"
        },
        "k4": "v4",
        "k5": {
            "k6": "v6"
        }
    },
    "k7": "v7",
    "k8": {
        "k9": "v9",
        "k10": {
            "k11": {
                "k12": "v12",
                "k13": "v13"
            },
            "k14": "v14"
        },
        "k15": {
            "k16": "v16"
        }

    },
    "k17": "v17",
    "k18": {
        "k19": "v19"
    }
}]
```

Comment: `openpyxl`はExcelファイルをExcelファイルのまま取り扱うのに適している感じなので、使うのは`pandas`の方が良いのでは？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

色々と方法はあるでしょうが、データ構造の入れ子的な部分を探し、それを引数にすると解り易い再帰関数になるかなと思います。

質問のケースですと、キーの値となる部分が表の全体の構造と同じで、再帰的な構造になっています。下の画像では、その内の一部、`k8` の値と `k10` の値をハイライトしています。それぞれ全体と同じアルゴリズムで処理できるはずです。

[image: 再帰部分]

ですから、表の一部を引数で受けとる関数により、再帰的に処理できます。

私は `openpyxl` は良く知らず、表の部分を表現するスマートな方法が解りませんので、下のコードでは、開始行、最終行、開始列、最終列、を数値で受けとっています。また、テストなど行なっていませんので、参考までに留めて下さい。

```py
import json
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

data = [
    #  1      2      3      4      5      6
    ["k1",  None,  None,  None,  None,  None],  #  1
    [None,  "k2",  None,  None,  None,  None],  #  2
    [None,  None,  "k3",  None,  None,  "v3"],  #  3
    [None,  "k4",  None,  None,  None,  "v4"],  #  4
    [None,  "k5",  None,  None,  None,  None],  #  5
    [None,  None,  "k6",  None,  None,  "v9"],  #  6
    ["k7",  None,  None,  None,  None,  "v7"],  #  7
    ["k8",  None,  None,  None,  None,  None],  #  8
    [None,  "k9",  None,  None,  None,  "v9"],  #  9
    [None,  "k10", None,  None,  None,  None],  # 10
    [None,  None,  "k11", None,  None,  None],  # 11
    [None,  None,  None,  "k12", None,  "v12"], # 12
    [None,  None,  None,  "k13", None,  "v13"], # 13
    [None,  None,  "k14", None,  None,  "k14"], # 14
    [None,  "k15", None,  None,  None,  None],  # 15
    [None,  None,  "k16", None,  None,  "v16"], # 16
    ["k17", None,  None,  None,  None,  "v17"], # 17
    ["k18", None,  None,  None,  None,  None],  # 18
    [None,  "k19", None,  None,  None,  "v19"], # 19
]

for row in data:
    ws.append(row)


def cell_range_to_dic(ws, row_first, row_last, column_first, column_last, depth=0):
    indent = " " * depth * 4
    print(f"{indent}-- cell_range_to_dic --")
    print(f"{indent}{row_first=} {row_last=} {column_first=} {column_last=} {depth=}")

    result = {}
    row = row_first

    # 左端に存在するキー毎にループする
    while row <= row_last:

        # キーは左端のセル
        key = ws.cell(row, column_first).value
        if key == None:
            raise ValueError(f"キー用のセルが空です: {row=}, {column_first=}")
        print(f"{indent}{key=}")

        # 右端のセルに値が有るかも知れない
        value_or_none = ws.cell(row, column_last).value

        # 次のループでは次のキーを扱う
        row += 1

        if value_or_none != None:
            # 右端のセルが値だった
            value = value_or_none
        else:
            # 後続行に含まれる再帰的構造が値だった
            # 次のキーまで読み飛ばす
            child_row_first = row
            while ws.cell(row, column_first).value == None and row <= row_last:
                row += 1

            # 読み飛ばした部分を再帰呼び出しで計算し、値とする
            value = cell_range_to_dic(
                ws, child_row_first, row - 1, column_first + 1, column_last, depth + 1)

        print(f"{indent}{value=}")
        result[key] = value

    return result


out_data = cell_range_to_dic(ws, 1, 19, 1, 6)

print("\n-- 結果 --\n")
print(json.dumps(out_data, sort_keys=False, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

冒頭のエクセルシートを"openpyxl.xlsx"というファイル名でSheet1に作成してあるものとします。

再帰関数を使用しなくてもこの場合は実現可能ですね。
・同一行にキーが複数あった場合、最初のキーのみ有効となります。
-> breakを削除すれば、同一行に複数キーを許容します。
・値がなければ、空の辞書型が値に代入されます。
・同一深さに重複キーがあっても、それより下層のキー内容も追加されます。
-> 例えば、k19->k1にしてみればわかります。

```py
import json
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("openpyxl.xlsx")
sh1 = wb['Sheet1']
wb.close()


xls_list = list()
for row_index in range(sh1.min_row, sh1.max_row+1):
    clm_list = list()
    for col_index in range(sh1.min_column, sh1.max_column+1):
        cell = sh1.cell(row_index, col_index)
        clm_list.append(cell.value)
    xls_list.append(clm_list)

# 項目が一番上にある前提で削除
xls_list.pop(0)

dict_array = np.asarray(xls_list)
row_num, clm_num = dict_array.shape

value_index = clm_num-1

disp_dict = dict()
_temp_dict_ = disp_dict
key_list = list()

for row_index in range(row_num):
    row_array = dict_array[row_index]
    val = row_array[value_index]
    for i, k in enumerate(row_array[:value_index]):
        if k is not None:
            if len(key_list) > i:
                key_list = key_list[:i]
                _temp_dict_ = disp_dict
                for k1 in key_list:
                    _temp_dict_ = _temp_dict_[k1]

            key_list.append(k)

            if val is not None:
                _temp_dict_.setdefault(k, val)
            else:
                _temp_dict_.setdefault(k, dict())
                _temp_dict_ = _temp_dict_[k]
            break


print(json.dumps(disp_dict, indent=2))
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
なるほど、再起関数なしでも作成可能なのですね。
disp_dictにどう代入しているのかわからないのですが、_temp_dictがdisp_dictを参照しているので、_temp_dictにkey,valueをsetdefaultすることでdisp_dictにも代入されるということでしょうか

Comment: pythonではlistやdictは参照で渡されます。Cでのポインタのようなものですね。よって参照で代入された_temp_dict_に値を代入すると、disp_dictに反映されます。注意点としては、最下層のintやstrなど値が入っている状態を_tmep_dict_に代入した場合、_tmep_dict_は参照型ではなく、単なる値なので、これに代入しても元のdisp_dictには反映されません。一度、テストコードを作成して、どう振舞うか確認されたら良いと思います。